# TextBox not updated in real time via BackgroundWorker with DataReceivedEventHandler enabled

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I need some help with BackgroundWorker. Using Visual Studio 2015 and its windows forms

I'm new to this kind of things and really have no idea how it works etc. The code i have so far is based on various posts on here.

worker_DoWork_ not being fired at all but no idea why. I believe this is something to do with DataRceivedEventHandler because when I move the  If i move the worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork_; and worker.RunWorkerAsync(); into button clicked event and disable DataReceivedEventHandler, method worker_DoWork_ is fired and I can update textBox with any static text assigned under DoSomeWork.

Also, I have no idea how to pass outline data into the text box via DoSomeWork.

Can someone help out please.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;


namespace CMD_testing
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    BackgroundWorker worker;
    private delegate void DELEGATE();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Process process;
        process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\\Project\Test\Data.bat";
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        //   process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputHandler);

        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        process.Start();
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
       // process.WaitForExit();
        // process.Close();
    }

    private void OutputHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
    {
        if (outLine.Data != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Im here...");

            worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork_;
            //worker.RunWorkerAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("Im here NOW");

            Console.WriteLine(outLine.Data);  //its outputed fine into the console 
        }

    }

    private void worker_DoWork_(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm at worker_DoWork_");
        Delegate del = new DELEGATE(DoSomeWork);
        this.Invoke(del);
    }

    private void DoSomeWork()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        textBox1.Text = "????";  // how to pass outline.Data in here

    }

}
```

}

Comment: why do you have commented  //worker.RunWorkerAsync();???

Comment: because I get an exception error saying Backgroundworker is already running and cannot run at the same time. Hence I believe DataReceivedHandler kicks one of but I might be wrong

Comment: You need to uncomment that line.  If you try to run it a second time, that's when it will crash.  So first, check if (!worker.IsBusy) { worker.RunWorkerAsync(); } - that will only allow it to run if it is not currently running.

Comment: Cool worked. However. My textBox was only updated once CMD has completed running. I need to update it in real time. Also, it seems that its seems the method is only called once rather then every time data is received from CMD.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you outline `RunWorkerAsync();`. This methods fires the DoWork-Event which handle your asynchronous code. Via the EventArgs of DoWork you can reuse your results back to your mainthread and print it to your textbox. You can get the result in the RunWorkerCompleted-Event. Here a small example based on your code:

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    BackgroundWorker worker;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_Completed;
    }

    private void OutputHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
    {
        if (outLine.Data != null)
        {
            if (!worker.IsBusy) //Check if Worker is working and avoid exception
               worker.RunWorkerAsync();     
        }
    }

    private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //Process some Long-Running Task
        Thread.Sleep(5000)
        e.Result = "Done!";
    }

    private void worker_Completed(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
       textbox.Text = e.Result.ToString();
    }
  }
}
```

Further you are maybe interested in [Task Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx) which make the handling of threads easier.

UPDATE:

You say:

> I want to update my Textbox in realtime.

This will print the text which your batchfile sends to Standardoutput directly in your textbox. So I don't think you need anymore.

```
private void OutputHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Data))
           BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { textBox1.Text = e.Data; }));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but my textBox is not being updated in real time i.e. each time a line is inserted into cmd window. It only outputs "Done!". Any idea why?

Comment: @TomPisz Your goal isn't clear to me. If you call worker.RunWorkerAsync(); this will exactly run your DoWork-Event one time. So for sure it results in one Done! in my example. Notice that Backgroundworker doesn't mean do sth, realtime. It just gives you the ability of a responsive UI on long running operations.

Comment: Sorry Sebi but this is what I have found on various websites and forums. I need to update the text box in real time and someone suggested to use backgrounder. I'm new to C# and this kind of events so not too sure how to do it ans simply try and error approach. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @TomPisz I updated my answer. I'm not quite sure if understand you the right way.

Comment: Thanks. You understood me correctly. CMD output needs to be redirected into textBox in real time. With your updated answer, I'm getting cross-thread exception error which I think was my reason for using backgrounder. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @TomPisz I updated the code. You need to Invoke then. I missed that OutputHandler is another thread before.

Comment: Can we move into quick chat? Its a small progress but still not there... as only one line is being updated rather. Easier to explain over chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132850/discussion-between-sebi-and-tom-pisz).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Sebi I have managed to get all issues sorted. It turns out I do not need a BackgroundWorker as some people suggested.

See the final code which works like a charm:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;


namespace CMD_testing
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Process process;
        process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\\Project\Test\Other Data.bat";
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
          process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputHandler);

        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        process.Start();
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process.Close();
    }

    private void OutputHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
    {
        if (outLine.Data != null)
        {
            BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { textBox1.AppendText(outLine.Data + Environment.NewLine); }));
        }

    }
  }
```

}